# How do I create a virtual directory in Tomcat 7?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

Tomcat is installed at C:\tomcat7\ but I want to deploy .war files in C:\myapp\xyz. For example, I might have C:\myapps\xyz\MyApp.war and I should be able to reach it with the path http://localhost:8080/MyApp.

I tried appending this to the bottom of c:\tomcat7\conf\server.xml

```
      <Host
          name="myapp"
          appBase="c:\myapps\xyz\"
          unpackWARs="true"
          autoDeploy="true">
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

This doesn't seem to work though as I don't see MyApp listed in the management console and I am not able to hit the URL. What else do I need to do?

Also, slightly unrelated but, how can I not have the name of the war file tied to the context name or URL path? For example, I want http://localhost/coolName to point to C:\myapps\xyz\MyApp.war.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the way Tomcat loads a war by filename is a tricky limitation.

I use a slightly different & OS-specific approach: "Symbolic Links". This isn't a direct answer, but may help you out anyway.

**Caveats:**

1. I use Linux, but this is
   also possible in Windows Vista &
   Windows 7.
2. using wars is still awkward using this method.
   Wars are zip files, so best    to
   unzip your war into a
   version-named folder.

**Solution:**

Create symbolic links (like a Virtual Directory on the filesystem) from your myapps folder into the webapps folder.

- This enables "coolName",
  "coolName-v2", etc.
- each webapp
  could potentially be kept in
  different places in the filesystem
- You can easily 'roll back' or 'upgrade' just by removing and re-adding symbolic links to different targets (make sure to "stop" the webapp while switching)

Linux:

```
ln -s target_name link_name
```

Vista/Windows 7:

```
mklink link_name target_name
```

In this way, you can still use c:\tomcat7\webapps\ , but specify symbolic links as follows:

```
mklink c:\tomcat7\webapps\coolName\ c:\myapps\xyz\webapp123\
```

(Note: For wars, you'd need to unzip the war first)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Your right in that you want to set the appBase paramete of the Host entry.  Here is a previous question that discusses what it takes under windows : [Apache Tomcat under Windows: Changing webapps default directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495457/apache-tomcat-under-windows-changing-webapps-default-directory)

As for how to change name of the app add a context.xml in the META-INF directory: [Separating war application name from war file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875413/separating-war-application-name-from-war-file-name/5875536#5875536)

Comment: I am still not able to see my app using the Host entry as specified in my initial post. It's possible I just don't know the default URL being used here because I do see my code initializing and I see it producing logs, but I'm not able to see it when I use the URL http://localhost:8080/MyApp