# How to set the correct windows path for tomcat webapps configuration

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, java-6

I am planning to change the webapps folder in tomcat server to use another folder.

I got to know that to do this we need to change appBase attribute in server.xml file, but how to give the full path in windows environment?

It is not detecting if I give something like below

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="C:\Users\webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

Could you please suggest how to do it. I am new to using tomcat

Comment: Try using `/` instead of ``\``, since the ``\`` is sometimes used as an escape character.

Comment: You mean 'C:/Users/webapps'? I tried it but no use

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. StackOverflow messed up my comment, because it also treats ``\`` as an escape character.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably escaping your backslashes.  Try this:

```
appBase="C:\\Users\\webapps"
```

Comment: Tried that also

Comment: can you try appBase="file:C:/Users/webapps"  Also check your permissions on that folder to make sure tomcat can acces it.

Comment: Hi, I tired using that, but no use

Comment: did you try the solutions from this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495457/apache-tomcat-under-windows-changing-webapps-default-directory

Comment: Yes I tried all of them, but my doubt is why different ways are working for different people even from the link that you shared?

Comment: I finally solved it by creating a shortcut from my customs folder to that webapps folder